# How to check whether a List contains a specified element using SQL IN operator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a multiselect dropdown list and if user select multi checkboxes in dropdown then I save these checkboxes values in `List` and then using `ROWFILTER` I applied `IN` operator on this list but I didn't got result according to dropdown selection.

```cs
List<string> Transpoters = new List<string>();              
foreach (ListItem item in TransporterDropDownList1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected) Transpoters.Add("'" + item.Value + "'");
}
ReportViewer.Reset();
DateTime fDate = DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.Value);
DataTable dt = GetDate(DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker1.Value), DateTime.Parse(datetimepicker2.Value));
if (MillDropDownList2.SelectedIndex > -1 && TransporterDropDownList1.SelectedIndex > -1 && Contract_Number.Value.Trim() == "")
{
    DataView Dv = new DataView(dt);
    Dv.RowFilter = "Mill_Name= '" + MillDropDownList2.SelectedValue + "' AND Transporter_Name IN  (" + string.Join(",", Transpoters.ToArray()) +")";
                    DataTable filter = new DataTable();
                    filter = Dv.ToTable();
    ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", filter);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"RPT/MolassesLifting.rdlc";
    ReportParameter[] rptParams = new ReportParameter[]
    {
        new ReportParameter("FromDate",datetimepicker1.Value),
        new ReportParameter("Todate",datetimepicker2.Value)
    };
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(rptParams);
    ReportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: if you set a breakpoint at `Dv.RowFilter`, is the value of the RowFilter what you expect? You look like you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection here as well. You shouldn't pass values through to your query that can possibly be manipulated by clients.

Comment: sir I have selected values in List but want to apply IN operator on these list values.

Comment: what's the text value if your going to evaluate this expression? "Mill_Name= '" + MillDropDownList2.SelectedValue + "' AND Transporter_Name IN  (" + string.Join(",", Transpoters.ToArray()) +")";
                DataTable filter = new DataTable();

Comment: There is only one list in your code: `transpoters`. Is this the list you want to use the `In` operator on? Of so, use Linq `Contains`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) like in the following statement?

```
$"AND CHARINDEX(Transporter_Name, '{string.Join(",", Transpoters)}' > 0"
```

Comment: @Scarface1122 Please note that this leaves your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because the user WILL be able to change the contents of TransporterDropDownList1 by editing the HTML code . I would advise to refactor your code by adding parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

To use In operator first we need to change the list in this pattern  ('eleme1','elem2','elem3','elem4') so I used String Builder. And then pass the string builder to IN operator.

```
List<string> Transpoters = new List<string>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (ListItem item in TransporterDropDownList1.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected) { 

                        Transpoters.Add("'"+item.Value+"'");
                        sb.Append("'"+item+"'").Append(",");
                    }
                }
                string test = sb.ToString();
```